# Dynamic Create $input in Laravel Controller to Insert data into table ( Error due to Foreach loop not working properly)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

#### Respected Sir/Ma'am, I have different product and I want to create a dynamic $input in controller to save product information into database

---

Example

```
    $imput['name'] = $request->get('name');
    $imput['price'] = $request->get('price');
    $imput['description'] = $request->get('description');
```

---

#### To create above input dynamically in controller I try to use foreach loop and pass Input key and value from Frontend side

---

Example

```
    [["name", "biryani"], ["size", "full"], ["price", "200"], ["description", "chicken + rice"], ["url", 
    …],…]
    0: ["name", "biryani"]
    1: ["size", "full"]
    2: ["price", "200"]
    3: ["description", "chicken + rice"]
    4: ["url",…]
    5: ["modelName", "chickenBiryani"]
```

---

#### Code i write in controller

(where i do mistake , this code not working also please give answer which I mention in below code comment , Thank You)

```
  public function upload($productInfo)
    {
     $input=[];
        foreach ($productInfo as $data) {
             // return $productInfo -- this return data
            // return $data -- this return throw error , why this happen
            foreach ($data as $val) {
            // return $val -- this return data
                if ($val[0] == 'modelName') {
                    $modelName = '\\App\\' . $val[1];
                } else {
                    $input[$val[0]] = $val[1];
                }
            }
        }
        $model = new $modelName;
        $model::create($input);
        return response()->json(['msg' => 'Profile Image Upload Succeessfully']);
    }
```

---

#### Please help me sir i am new in Laravel

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you declared `$input = []`, but using `$imput` in the loop. That means `$input` will always be an empty array.
Secondly, `Model::create()` accepts a single associative array, not multidimensional array e.g:

```
[
"name" => "Name",
"user_id" => 23
]
```

Finally, you might need to fletch out your code to eliminate that double loop. But I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, so can't suggest edits